# Handle money and currencies in javascript multiplying and dividing by 100

Tags: javascript, floating-point, numbers, decimal, currency

I'm writing an app for myself. I need to handle money and currencies.

I read [this](https://frontstuff.io/how-to-handle-monetary-values-in-javascript) and I want to try the second approach:

> You can multiply floats into integers before you calculate, then divide them back.
>
> (0.2 * 100 + 0.01 * 100) / 100 // returns 0.21
>
> It’s a fine solution but requires extra calculations either on object construction or on each manipulation. This isn’t necessarily draining on performances, but still more process work than necessary.

With my backend I store values in `int64`.

#### QUESTION

Let's take `1.1`.

`1.1 * 100 = 110.00000000000001`!!!

How can I be safe for all operations?

It's safe to always use `(1.1 * 100).toFixed()`?

Comment: *"How can I be safe for all operations?"* don't deal with the actual currency, always store and do math with it's smallest denomination. For example cents over dollars. And only when you need to render the amount convert/format it to what your customers expect to see (dollars, not cents). That way you get rid of all the floating point math and you don't have to convert back and forth all the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string. If you need an integer, use `Math.round(1.1 * 100)`. As long as you are multiplying by 100 there should be no issues.

Comment: @Thomas, this not answer my question. I know I can use cents (smallest denomination). I'm asking something else.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's a different question.

Comment: @GOTO 0 you'are right! Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas: Using integers with the smallest denomination does not solve all problems. Neither integers, decimal fixed-point, binary fixed-point, decimal floating-point, nor binary floating-point can represent the unit price of items sold three for a dollar. Nor can they compute interest without exceeding available precision after a few compoundings (often just one term). There is no format that magically solves these problems; the only solution is for the programmer to know what they are doing.

Comment: https://currency.js.org/ this can relief or, using bigint and storing values 100times bigger to store cents  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt